# lenovo A6000 not booting

Tags: custom-roms

I have a Lenovo a6000 which I recently flashed and when it rebooted I cant even see the logo and if I press the power button it just vibrates again and again in a few intervals,I tried to boot into recovery by pressing volume up and power button but that was also no use what can I do to get into recovery

Comment: Could you share the tutorial you used to flash your phone? Also, do you see display lights turning on when you hold the power button, or the phone only responds through a quick vibration? I guess its bricked, but just to be sure, can you boot into fastboot mode by using some button combinations?

Answer (score 1):

To get into Recovery you need to keep both VOLUME <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys pressed down and hold .. Also press the POWER button till you see the Lenovo logo. Then let go of the POWER button but keep the VOLUME Buttons (both <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>) pressed down until you get to RECOVERY mode.

Hope you have backed up the Stock ROM before you did the Port ROM install.

Another way to get to Recovery is to flash a new Copy of RECOVERY (CWM).

http://techolaty.net/how-to-install-cwm-root-lenovo-a6000-smartphone/

If your phone is not booting then, keep the Volume Down button pressed down with the POWER Button, then release the Power button on seeing the Lenovo Logo, also release the Volume button.

This screen looks almost the same as the Lenovo Boot Screen however if you look closer, to the bottom you will see

> Powered BY
>   android
>
> Powerkey long press can reboot phone

BINGO!! You are in Fast boot mode

Now follow the link above and start off with

STEP 3:

Open the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot` directory and press and hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key and right click anywhere inside the folder at the empty space and choose "open command window here".

Now type:

```
adb devices
```

This will not show any authorised devices. Basically it will not show anything.

Now type:

```
fastboot boot recovery.img
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for your problem is to flash the stock firmware for your phone using the official tool from Lenovo, after getting your phone working again, you can then flash any custom rom if you want (i don't!), to flash your phone with the stock firmware follow the guide from [here](http://lenovo-forums.ru/topic/12627-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-lenovo-a6000/) (it's in russian but with pics - also google is your friend), and for the firmware itself you can download it from [here](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9GUn/tDJNaqUz3).